# c++ list class vs2010 Ultimate

Tags: c++, list, class

I'm new in C++ (im using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate) and i have a problem to destroy a class with had a std::list, my code is:

```
#include "p_list.h"

int main(){
    p_list uno;
    uno.~p_list();
    return 0;
}
```

and the class p_list is :

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LISTADO_H
#define LISTADO_H
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class p_list
{
public:
    list<int> first; 

    p_list(void);

    ~p_list(void);
};

#endif
```

when i execute the code appears this error

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/51/dibujopfw.jpg/]

i dont understand why, and if a change the std::list for an std::vector, the code execute perfectly...but i nead an std::list

thnxs

Comment: You rarely ever need to call the destructor yourself like that. In this case, it's called when `uno` goes out of scope. The most common time you would indirectly call it is using `delete`, but that's obsolete. From your class details, providing an explicit destructor seems pointless as well. You also have `using namespace std;` in the global namespace of the header, which is something that no one using that header should have to deal with. Finally, `#pragma once` and the standard header guard both do the same thing, but the latter is part of standard C++. I would choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Textbook case of "overthinking it". C++ is actually a lot easier than people seem to think...

Comment: Well, I shouldn't say header guards are a language feature, but rather `#pragma once` is not. I guess header guards are just something you can do using no extensions.

Comment: Post your full code if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

The list has [automatic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) and will will get destroyed on the scope exit:

```
#include "p_list.h"

int main(){
    p_list uno;
    return 0;
}  // destructor is called on scope exit
```

By calling the destructor manually, you are provoking an attempt to destroy the object twice.

Comment: @user1661182 the error must be due to something else. You really don have to call the destructor here.

Comment: @user1661182: Do you make the mistake of calling `first.~list()` in the destructor as well?

Comment: @Etori I cannot reproduce the problem. If I do what you claim to have done except for using my main function, compiling and linking with GCC 4.8, there is no problem at all.

Comment: i think that the problem is in the instalation of the VS2010, i will reinstall and comment

Comment: i reinstall the VS2010 and the problem persist, i will try to code with Dev C++...i think the problem is Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

you've called the destructor manually, and then, when exiting the `main()` function the destructor gets called once more automatically.

We don't have the p_list.cpp ; could something be deleted there twice?

Comment: the code in cpp is:  #include "p_listado.h"


p_listado::p_listado(void)
{
}


p_listado::~p_listado(void)
{
 
}

Answer (score 0):

`uno` will be allocated on the stack. This also means that when it goes out of scope, its destructor will be called **automatically**. You do not need to (*and should not*) call it manually.

The same is true for member variables in a class. If they're not allocated on the heap, then their destructors in turn will get called when the class' destructor gets called.

You can see this for yourself, if you put a print statement inside your constructor and destructor:

```
#include "listado.h"
#include <iostream>
p_list::p_list(void)
{
    std::cout<<"plist constructor called\n";
}

p_list::~p_list(void)
{
    std::cout<<"plist destructor called\n";
}
```

Next, remove any manual calls to p_list's destructor, like juanchopanza has suggested and watch the destructor get called automatically.

If your listado.cpp file contains only constructors and destructors, delete it and use this:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LISTADO_H
#define LISTADO_H
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class p_list
{
public:
    list<int> first; 

    p_list(void){};

    ~p_list(void){};
};

#endif
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when a comment uno.~p_list, the error shows too. And notice that when I use Vector instead of list, the program run well

Comment: im not using any methods, becouse i try to concentrate the area of the problem,per se  i create a new proyect (the proyect you can see) where is the necesary code to show that error (and no more code)